# Enabling std::move for const non literal types

Tags: c++

One of the problems with const member literal type variables is that `std::move` defaults to using the copy constructor instead of the move constructor. This limits move assignment in classes containing const literal types to unsafe exceptions.

The following code appears to enable actually moving the contents of a const, literal type.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template<class T>
std::remove_const_t<T>& de_const(T& obj) noexcept {
    return *static_cast<std::remove_cv_t<T>*>(const_cast<void*>(static_cast<const volatile void*>(&obj)));
}

struct A {
    const std::string s;
};

int main()
{
    A a{ "asdfasdasdfasdfasdfasdf" }, b{ "12341234123412341234" };
    std::destroy_at(&a.s);
    std::construct_at(&de_const(a.s), std::move(de_const(b.s)));
    std::cout << "a.s=" << a.s << "\n"; // now contains prior contents of b
    std::cout << "b.s=" << b.s << "\n"; // b is now valid but gutted

    /* Correct outputs
    a.s=12341234123412341234
    b.s=
    */
}
```

However, while the `std::construct_at` is legal (since c++20) when transparently replacing a destructed `const std::string` with a `std::string` I suspect that treating the "from" string as non const is UB. At least technically. Note that it is UB when the literal type is a complete const object and A is not in the example.

Is it UB?

Here's [compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/qsP3Kxn73) showing success with MSVC, GCC and CLANG

Comment: Pretty sure this is UB.  `b.s` is `const`, but you've modified it: https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.dcl#dcl.type.cv-4

Comment: A `const` object cannot be moved, by definition. Because, by definition, a real move operation leaves the moved-from object in some "valid but unspecified state". A `const` object's state, by definition, cannot be changed. The End.

Comment: @NathanOliver Sure looks like it. While it can be modified in place if you first destruct it it appears you can't steal it's guts while alive. Unfortunate because it forces using less efficient container manipulations with const, non-literal variables. Interesting though in that after moving the next thing in line is destruction.

Comment: The great thing about c++ is you can do whatever the hell you want as long as you aren’t upset when the compiler zigs when it used to zag. That being said, what exactly is a “safe exception”. It sounds like that is the real problem you are having but I’m not 100% clear on what you mean when you say you’re “limited to unsafe exceptions”

Comment: @Taekahn As of c++20 one can copy b.s to a.s by destroying a.s then constructing a new a.s using b.s. But that requires a new heap allocation hence is not exception safe.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik A const object that isn't part of a complete const can certainly be changed by ending it's lifetime then transparently replacing it by a different object so long as it's the same type. This was a major change in  c++20. However, changing it in the manner I used is UB.

Comment: Maybe so, but before you can "end its lifetime", the const object needs to be moved, otherwise after its lifetime is ended there's nothing left to move. But a const object cannot be moved. So, in the end, you still can't move a const object.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik That's exactly the problem. You while you can change a const object w/o UB, you can't move it w/o UB.

Comment: Curious: why the complicated multi-cast in `de_const` instead of simply `return const_cast<std::remove_const_t<T>&>(obj);`? I don't see the benefit of transitioning through a `void*`.

Comment: @JaMiT. There isn't a reason. It's left over code from an earlier version that had  To and From template arguments I didn't simplify.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the change in C++20 to allow destroy+construct of a const object was exactly for this use case. So while the moving of `from` might be UB it probably shouldn't be. Maybe write a paper to change/clarify this in the standard and allow it? Having the destroy+construct for const without move semantic seems rather limiting.